# How to add a border at the bottom of every <li>?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a border to the bottom of every list item, however it appears to only add it to the bottom of the entire list:
[image: a]

here is my code:
http://scratchpad.io/abusive-stage-1825

Thanks.

Comment: css:

li {
border-bottom: 1px;
}

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
li { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this may help you, try adding li{border:1px solid red;width:50px;}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
li{border:1px solid red;width:50px;}
</style>
<h4>An Unordered List:</h4>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above two answers do not work for you, which they should, you could always set li's as their own separate class and then refer to that in your CSS.